# Parse How to Group By similar objects in One object?

Tags: parse-platform, group-by

I am using Parse for Group Chat and Private Chat both. 
I get stuck in a situation

**where in Chat("one table using for both private and group")**

there are columns such as

**"Groupid, Senderid, ReceiverId and Status"**

Here one user sends more than one text msgs so I want to collect all the chats of that user in One Group so one user can have joined more than 1 groups so I want the all chats of particular group in one bunch so if there are chats in 5 groups then there should 5 objects with their chats such as Group By functionality.

Comment: It's difficult to give meaningful feedback without knowing more about the class structures. Please try to be as descriptive as possible and make the question as clear as possible. As it stands, this seems to be an open-ended question in need of editing.

Comment: Okay Russell lemme try again but i want to know something about parse, Does parse support GroupBy query as in SQl if not is there any alternative solution for this. And thnx for the reply.

Comment: When in doubt, look at the documentation: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html. Again, the question is so broad that it's impossible to properly answer your question. Parse uses MongoDB as a backend however they allow you to add numerous sort and ordering criteria to queries. You can order by numeral values, alphabetical, dates, geolocations, and more.